# Loading Module on an Air/Android application

Tags: android, apache-flex, module, air, apk

I'm building an Air for Android App and I'm having problems loading a flex module. Does anyone know if loading modules is possible???

I built a simple app with just a ModuleLoader in it, which loads a mx:module. The module has only a simple mx:Label with a "Hello World" text.

I build a .air with this. Then I build a .apk with the followin adt command.

> adt -package -target apk-emulator -storetype pkcs12 -keystore certificate.p12 hello.apk hello.air

The application works just fine when running it on the PC, but when I do it on the apk-emulator it just goes blank and throws error #2032.

Answer (score 2):

I've just solved it. You can't generate the apk using the air file, at least not the way I did it.

I've just generated the apk using the following:

> adt -package -target apk -storetype pkcs12 -keystore certificate.p12 AndroidApp.apk AndroidApp-app.xml AndroidApp.swf module.swf

AndroidApp.swf was my main application and module.swf was my module. It worked like a charm :D

Bye!

Gabriel.-